# Spacing a header

Tags: html, css

I'm banging my head against a wall, here.  Any advice would be appreciated.

I want a header that I'll use on my pages, where the image and text will change but the style will not.  All of the images will be 399x207 and I want the title box to the left of the image to fill the space.  I want the title box to be 207px tall.

I've tried tables (the current version) and other methods but nothing seems to be what I need / want.

Here's the weird part of my request, if anyone answering could guide / hint instead of doing it for me.  It's homework and I'm keen to learn.  Thanks!

```
h1 {
color: #f4ead0;
text-align: center;
}

h2 {
background-color: #5d432c;
color: #f4ead0;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-align: center;
}

table, td {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border-spacing: 0;
}

#header {
border-radius: 15px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 70%;
min-width: 700px;
}

#wrapper {
border-radius: 15px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 70%;
min-width: 700px;
background-color: #745336;
}
.box {
border-radius: 15px;
border: 2px solid #bd6e02;
text-align: center;
background-color: #745336;  
}

<!-- Header -->
    <div id="header">
        <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td  class="box" colspan="2">
                <h1>A Brief Discussion of Fractals</h1>
                <h2>The Mandelbrot Set</h2>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <img class="box" src="mandelbrot.gif" alt="Part of the Mandelbrot Set">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[image: Current Header]

Comment: don't use tables. Unless it is a requirement for your homework... Using tables for website layout etc is very very outdated and imo bad practice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might work, although I haven't tested it.

First, make the first `<td>` 100% wide, so it will try to fit inside the whole table, the content on the second `<td>` will collapse.

Next, put a `white-space:nowrap` on the `<tr>`, so nothing inside it will collapse.

```
<div id="header">
    <table style="width:100%" border=1>
    <tr style="white-space:nowrap">
        <td  class="box" colspan="2" width="100%">
            <h1>A Brief Discussion of Fractals</h1>
            <h2>The Mandelbrot Set</h2>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img class="box" src="mandelbrot.gif" alt="Part of the Mandelbrot Set">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it!  I had to change a couple of things and I'm still working on getting the image to be the same size as the left box, but thanks!

Comment: Using a table for a layout is not a best practices. Tables are for data representation only. Use divs instead

Comment: True, you should use divs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `caption` in Bootstrap... [Check this out](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_thumbnails.htm). BTW, like your spirit to learn it yourself. You may have to apply some CSS too.